# Using ngx-sortablejs with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Ngx-sortablejs with Angular 8.0.1 does not work and does not show any errors.

Connected according to the documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sortablejs

As I understand, the support of Angular 8 is already implemented, maybe someone has already faced this issue?

Comment: Can you replicate this over a sample stackblitz? It's hard to determine what you did based on your question. It's working fine for me.

Comment: Here the example: http://scherbakov.com.ua/sortable-test.zip

Comment: Is this thing hosted somewhere? Maybe on GitHub? I can't really install all the dependencies RN and want to check this thing online. Maybe o StackBlitz. I can do that if you have this thing hosted as a Github Repo.

Comment: This is strange, but the same project on stackblitz works fine, but if I download it locally, it does not work

Comment: Yeap. Even I was able to make it run on StackBlitz. Hence the Comment :P

Comment: https://github.com/3ddesign/ngx-sortable